# Facebook Unity3d Extends UnityPlayerActivity breaking other plugins that do the same

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

So I've already go one 3rd party plugin that extends UnityPlayerActivity, plus we extend that to sprinkle our own stuff in, and now along comes the facebook sdk for unity with it's own extended UnityPlayerActivity.

Why do these 3rd party SDK's all think they're so darn special that they can just inject themselves into this precious position? Ok, rant done...

Is there any hope facebook could fix their SDK to not do this? Asking here since they don't have their own support forum...

In the mean time, is there any way of reconciling existence of two extensions of the same class? Is the only way to hack these third party jars and rewrite a single UnityPlayerActivity subclass?

Facebook SDK is nice and clean (compared to prime31's), but pretty much unusable on android for us in current state :(

**Update**:

Well, I've gone ahead and edited my own subclass adding the one call that facebooks subclass had in it, and it sort of works. At least it's getting further.

Now I'm getting a NullPointerException from inside Facebooks LoginAction class:

```
W/System.err( 1166): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity     {com.fluik.WordMeisterFree/com.facebook.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
W/System.err( 1166):    at  android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3016)
W/System.err( 1166):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2971)
W/System.err( 1166):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2949)
W/System.err( 1166):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
W/System.err( 1166):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1251)
W/System.err( 1166):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
W/System.err( 1166):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
W/System.err( 1166):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
W/System.err( 1166):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err( 1166):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
W/System.err( 1166):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
W/System.err( 1166):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
W/System.err( 1166):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/System.err( 1166): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
W/System.err( 1166):    at com.facebook.LoginActivity.onPause(LoginActivity.java:121)
W/System.err( 1166):    at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:5206)
```

Where it looks like it's trying to set visibility on a progress bar that can't be found:

```
findViewById(R.id.com_facebook_login_activity_progress_bar).setVisibility(8);
```

It seems to find it find on view create, so maybe something's destroying it before this code gets called. Is the source for the FB SDK available so i can try fixing this stuff myself?

**Update**:

Just confirmed that even putting the original facebook launch activity in, com.facebook.unity.FBUnityPlayerActivity, I get the exact same crash. Am I the only one seeing this? Testing on a Nexus7....

Answer (score 3):

Update:

We're still stuck in Android with fighting over the main activity, but you can stick our code in whatever activity is at the top of the stack as shown here:

[Conflict with activity tags on android manifest: Facebook and Google Play Games in Unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18970822/conflict-with-activity-tags-on-android-manifest-facebook-and-google-play-games)

We think we've fixed the resource conflict problem, so if you're still seeing that, let us know.

Comment: Hey Aaron, thanks for the quick response! I did some more testing, and   have a very confusing result:

1. I dropped the Facebook SDK (newest one, 3.1.2) into own project, same bundle id and app id as my proj, works fine.

2. In my project I make the fb test scene the only one in build settings, all else being equal, and it fails with same crash (nullptr in LoginActivity)

I'm trying to figure out what's different between the two builds since they really should be identical. One curiosity is that the ProgressBar in working project says "nearby" and in not working says "false", any ideas?

Comment: Update: I copied the 'res' folder from failing project to fb demo project, voila, same broken behavior. So yeah, there's some problem with resource conflicts. Will keep digging...

Comment: Talked to our android guy, and he's come across similar issues with an internal plugin. I don't understand it all to well, but basically he's saying that the problem lies in how Unity compiles R resources file and actually modifies it multiple times sometimes changing the ID values after the fact. What we've found on our plugins is that the safer way is to find resources using something like this: activity.getResources().getIdentifier("name", "id", packageName);
If you guys want to update just the LoginActivity to do so, I'd be happy to test it for you in my project...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on dynamic lookup. we have some concerns internally about the performance of that approach, apparently the lookup degrades linearly with the number of properties R has? Then again, slow is better than broken.

Comment: So is this something that is under consideration? Any idea on an ETA? Just wondering if I should hold out for a fix (my preference) or switch back to using prime31 plugin...

Comment: This is a top priority task for us. ETA or new SDK by end of week, thanks for your patience.

Comment: Just got the new SDK (4.2.1) and it crashes in the same place with the same error  :(

Comment: Hey Klaus, sorry we didn't get the resource thing fixed in 4.2.1. I have an experimental SDK though, would you be willing to give it a try? Here is a link: http://beta-fb-unity-sdks.parseapp.com/v4.2.5/FacebookSDK.unitypackage Sorry for the delay, and thanks for your help!

Comment: @KlausRubba - one more thing: this requires 4.2+ Unity SDK. One other thing I'd love is a reproducible test case: If you can stick a project somewhere that I could grab to test that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Hey Aaron, I got a similar build from another thread to address an ios private api issue, but had already ripped out the offending plugin. I'll try putting it back and seeing if this update fixed that issue on Monday. Sorry I hadn't checked this thread in a while and didn't get email update...

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and it can be workarounded by using an android project as library project in eclipse containing only the res files from the sdk.

Remove the overriden FBUnityPlayerActivity and R class files from de SDK jar, and link this library project to your Unity eclipse project.

Finally move the FBUnityPlayerActivity OnActivityResult code to your UnityActivity OnActivityResult implementation.

Remember that your manifest should point to your activity and not to the FBUnityPlayerActivity (the one you removed), defined by the sdk editor scripts.

Also, check this http://prime31.com/docs#androidGeneral , they state:

Note: there is a major issue with regard to any Android plugins that have external assets stored in the "res" folder. Currently, only 1 plugin with external assets can be deployed in an application. This is a limitation with regard to how assets are handled with Android as a whole. We are always on the looking for a solution that does not require recompiling Java code directly and have not yet found one.

So we can't expect to have a clean solution for this soon.