# Conflict with activity tags on android manifest: Unity Facebook and Vuforia in Unity3d

Tags: android-intent, unity-game-engine, vuforia, facebook-unity-sdk

Both Unity Facebook and Vuforia(AR) plugins require that I use android.intent.action.MAIN and android.intent.action.LAUNCHER in the Android Manifest.

I had tried Brain's [Brain's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18970822/conflict-with-activity-tags-on-android-manifest-facebook-and-google-play-games), but my problem can't be solved. 
The application can't receive the FB.Login callback.

And the status of FB is OPENING.

In my situation, I am using Vuforia and Unity Facebook plugin. And the Vuforia require that use android.intent.action.MAIN and android.intent.action.LAUNCHER.

```
    <activity android:name="com.qualcomm.QCARUnityPlayer.QCARPlayerProxyActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Anyone have any idea to solve that?

I think the coming Unity-Facebook plugin will support break this limitation. As I find other 3rd party like Prime31. Their FB plugin for android is not required use *android.intent.action.MAIN*

Thanks!!

Comment: Hey Edric, what activity is on top of the stack when your game is running? this behavior happens when the session result handler isn't getting called.

Can you stick some log messages in and make sure this is getting called? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Aaron, thanks for your reply. I am newbie of Android. Can you tell me that how to check the activity stack?

Comment: Hi Edric, trying sticking a log statement in your main activity in onActivityResult and just see if that gets called. If it does, can you send my your project? I'll try debugging it. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Aaron, 

I capture the log. Init & Login is called. 

D/FBUnitySDK﹕ init called with params: {"appId":"162774157260206","cookie":true,"xfbml":true,"channelUrl":"/channel.html","frictionlessRequests":true}D/FBUnitySDK﹕ sending to Unity OnInitComplete({})
I/Unity﹕ FB.Init completed
D/FBUnitySDK﹕ afterReadPermissionCallback Session state changed:OPENING
I/Unity﹕ StopQCAR
D/PowerManagerService﹕ releaseWakeLockLocked flags=0x0 tag=Unity-ProjectRequestedWakeLock
D/PowerManagerService﹕ acquireWakeLock flags=0x1a tag=Unity-ProjectRequestedWakeLock uid=10045 pid=26922
I/Unity﹕ StartQCAR

Comment: The Session state changed to OPENING. I waited for a long period, but the state doesn't change. I pressed the login again and the state changed to FAIL then back to OPENING.

Thanks Aaron

Comment: Hi Aaron, anyway I can send the project to you? Thanks

Comment: Hi Edric, I don't see an onActivityResult log line here so that's probably it. Feel free to send your project, just email it to unity-sdk@fb.com. Thanks!