# Facebook plugin for Unity (v5.0.2 BETA) is missing bin folder

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I was forced to use this version of plugin because with v 4.3.6 there are problems with Vuforia:

[Conflict with activity tags on android manifest: Unity Facebook and Vuforia in Unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19172455/conflict-with-activity-tags-on-android-manifest-unity-facebook-and-vuforia-in-u)

When importing the v5.0.2 plugin into an empty project and then building the InteractiveConsole scene I receive an exception

> AndroidJavaException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.facebook.unity.FB at UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.CheckException ()
>   [0x00000] in :0  at
>   UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.CallStaticObjectMethod (IntPtr clazz,
>   IntPtr methodID,  at
>   UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject._CallStatic[AndroidJavaObject]
>   (System.String  at
>   UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject.CallStatic[AndroidJavaObject]
>   (System.String methodName,  at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject.FindClass
>   (System.String name) [0x00000] in

Tried to copy the  **bin** folder from the v4.3.6 plugin. After that Init runs fine. But after trying to login I get a spinner and in a second or two nothing else happens and it hides.

How can I fix that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We fixed this and have a new version, v5.0.3, up here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/downloads/?campaign_id=282184128580929&placement=SDK_list
Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same problem. You can fix it by copying the facebook folder from your Plugins->Android directory out of Unity, then building it in Eclipse and copying the new bin folder back into your Unity project.