# Conflict with activity tags on android manifest: Facebook and Prime31 plugins in Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk, prime31

I'm trying to get a project to work with both the Facebook Unity plugin and (several) Prime31 plugins.  I'm trying to create my own activity that extends the Prime31 activity and also incorporates the workaround for Facebook given here: [Conflict with activity tags on android manifest: Facebook and Google Play Games in Unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18970822/conflict-with-activity-tags-on-android-manifest-facebook-and-google-play-games)

So far, I've got a class that looks like this:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.facebook.Session;

public class DQUnityPlayerActivity extends com.prime31.UnityPlayerProxyActivity
{
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    super.onCreate(arg0);
  }

  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
  } 
}
```

I've compiled it with javac, packed it up as a .jar file, and put it in /Assets/Plugins/Android.  I modified our AndroidManifest.xml like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.unity3d.player" android:installLocation="preferExternal" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
  <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:name=".DQUnityPlayerActivity" android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
etc...
```

Now here's where I'm stuck: at this point, when I try to run it on my test device, the class isn't found.  ADB shows me this:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(16863): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(16863): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.dqsoft.ChampHearts/com.dqsoft.ChampHearts.DQUnityPlayerActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.dqsoft.ChampHearts.DQUnityPlayerActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/mnt/asec/com.dqsoft.ChampHearts-1/pkg.apk]
E/AndroidRuntime(16863):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
E/AndroidRuntime(16863):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
E/AndroidRuntime(16863):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
E/AndroidRuntime(16863):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
E/AndroidRuntime(16863):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(16863):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(16863):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
E/AndroidRuntime(16863):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(16863):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime(16863):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
E/AndroidRuntime(16863):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
E/AndroidRuntime(16863):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(16863): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.dqsoft.ChampHearts.DQUnityPlayerActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/mnt/asec/com.dqsoft.ChampHearts-1/pkg.apk]
E/AndroidRuntime(16863):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
E/AndroidRuntime(16863):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
E/AndroidRuntime(16863):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
E/AndroidRuntime(16863):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
E/AndroidRuntime(16863):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
E/AndroidRuntime(16863):    ... 11 more
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: to clarify: is the path to your class DQUnityPlayerActivity under com/dqsoft/ChampHearts/? I didn't know that .DQUnityPlayerActivity actually worked for your androidmanifest.xml, I typically put the full path in, though it is clear from the error that the full path was inferred.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your exported jar file inside Assets/Plugins/Android/ folder and make sure in your DQUnityPlayerActivity class you have this line:
`package com.dqsoft.ChampHearts;`