# CardboardActivity conflict with UnityPlayerNativeActivity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-manifest, google-cardboard

I need two plugins in my app. One uses CardboardActivity and another one uses UnityPlayerNativeActivity. Both of these activities requires:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

But obviously I can't make both of them MAIN and LAUNCHER. I know there is a way to re-compile one plugin to extend another one. But that method requires source code from one of the plugin. So I am kind of stuck here.

Does anyone run into something like this before?

Comment: See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/18971204/2245773.

Comment: Yes, I have tried [Conflict with activity tags on android manifest: Facebook and Google Play Games in Unity3d] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18970822/conflict-with-activity-tags-on-android-manifest-facebook-and-google-play-games/18971204#18971204) It doesn't work for me maybe (1) I still did something wrong or (2) I am not dealing with Facebook plugin, in Facebook's case, once user logged in, the activity ends and return result to another activity. But in my case both activities have to run at the same time.

Comment: I am hoping that since one of them is actually using UnityPlayerNativeActivity, which maybe also what CardboardActivity is extended from, maybe there is a way for me to just make CardboardActivity as MAIN and make another plugin work?